# How to delete a exact match on a string

Tags: r

i need to remove a certain part of string if it's a exact match with a couple of keys. For example in my dataframe i have the string "PCPSERGIO AUGUSTO DOS SANTOS" i need to remove the PCP at the start of this but not change remove any "p" from "FATURA - PHENIX".

example:

```
x <- c("PCPSERGIO AUGUSTO DOS SANTOS","FATURA - PHENIX")
x <- removestr(x,"[PCP]")
x
[1] "SERGIO AUGUSTO DOS SANTOS"  "FATURA - PHENIX"
```

i have tried using the str_remove function as well as the gsub function.

```
df <- str_remove_all(df,"[PcP]")
```

Comment: `sub("^PCP", "", x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the global sub function `gsub`:

```
gsub(pattern = "PCP", replacement = "", x = x)
```